# BAD INSTRUCTION arc4random_uniform

Tags: ios, swift

I was trying to do something about percentages but i think i did something wrong.

```
let randomNum = arc4random_uniform(25) + 71
let wrongNumber = 100 - Int(randomNum)
let firstWrong = wrongNumber - 10
var first = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(firstWrong))
var second = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(wrongNumber) - first)
var third = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(wrongNumber) - (first + second))
let plus = (UInt32(wrongNumber) - (first + second + third)) / 3
first = first + plus
second = second + plus
third = third + plus
let total = randomNum + first + second + third
if (total < 100) {
    first += (100 - total)
}
```

[It sometimes gives this BAD INSTRUCTION error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92hjM.png)

[And it usually works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEbru.png)

Comment: Don't post screen shots post your code. BTW your are trying to subtract from an unsigned integer `UInt32` and when it reaches the negative numbers it will obviously crash

Comment: thanks a lot it was my first question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is completely flawed, consider the first few lines:

```
let randomNum = arc4random_uniform(25) + 71 // values 71 ... 95
let wrongNumber = 100 - Int(randomNum) //values 5 ... 29
let firstWrong = wrongNumber - 10 // -5 ... 19
```

The maximum `randomNum` is `95`. Then `wrongNumber` is `5` and `firstWrong` is `-5`.

Then

```
var first = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(firstWrong))
```

has to crash when casting `-5` to an unsigned number.

Similar errors can happen on other lines if the values get into negatives.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i missed that it reaches the negative numbers